# How to calculate force exerted by vacuum from size and rpm of propeller used to create it?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum, fluid-statics

If a propeller of particular size pushes some volume of air out per unit time. How can the suction force be determined? How big of a particle can it suck?

Comment: What about losses and stall?

Comment: @SolarMike ignoring losses

Comment: And what about stall?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know how much it affects.

Comment: Then that gives you something to research...

Comment: @SolarMike I will try to learn about it. But   if we are ignoring both.